# Snowflake-sequences - Area - Circumference

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, area

> Consider the following inductively defined snowflakes-sequences: $S_1$ is an equilateral triangle with edge length $l_0$, and $S_{n+1}$ emerges from $S_n$ by dividing each edge by 3 and the middle third is replaced by an equilateral triangle with the according edge length.
>
> Let $F_n$ be the surface area and $U_n$ the circumference of the figure defined by $S_n$. 
>   Examine $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to see if they converge and determine the limit of sequence if possible.

Allright, first I tried drawing the situation because I think that I saw such a thing at some point and it looked kind of like what seems to be described in the exercise.

I only did it for $n=1,2,3$ because it gets very messy after 3.

[image]

That should be the correct pictures, right?

Anyway, I was thinking, that for $n\to \infty$ it should look very similar to a circle, correct? So I was thinking that the radius of that circle should be the distance from one edge of the triangle $S_1$ to the center of it? Meaning $r=cos(30°)\cdot \frac{l_0}{2}$. Which would give me $\pi r^2$ and $2\pi r$ for the surface area and the circumference of that sequence $S_n$? But I highly doubt that it could be that easy. Besides I don't have any way to prove that mathematically.

I asked my teacher for some advice but he said my approach was too mundane, but he didn't tell me whether the solution I came up with was correct or not.

I mean, I know we are dealing with sequences and series' here, but I don't know how to solve this one without an explicit sequence or series.

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the points of the original triangle remain part of the figure at every stage and the "concave vertices" of the first snowflake also remain part of subsequent figures. You might be able to show that these points define two circles between which the snowflake is constructed.

For the "circumference" you might care to prove that each iteration increases the length of the boundary by one third, so that the circumference of $S_2$ is four thirds times the circumference of $S_1$.

You might care to work out what happens to the area (since the figure is bounded, and the area is increasing, there will be a definite limit).